# Exclude all tagged posts from WP_Query loop

Tags: wp-query, tags

Does anyone know how to exclude all tagged posts from WP_Query loop?

I can do it with **'tag__not_in'** for specific tag IDs – see below:

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'poetry', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'ASC', 'tag__not_in' => array(8, 9) ) ); ?>
```

But I was wanting to eliminate all tagged posts without updating the tag IDs in the **'tag__not_in'**.

Cheers,

Damian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the tax_query parameter with the taxonomy set as post_tag. See the following previous answer:

[Get all posts without tags](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/114978/get-all-posts-without-tags)

Comment: No problem, could you mark the question as answered?